# React native fetch image location data from local database error unexpected token ","

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to fetch some image loc from my local database, while I try to show it as a text it works perfectly fine but when I try to pass it on  it gives me an error

```
const Products = () => {

const ProductCard = ({data}) => {
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
             <Image source={require({data.productImage})} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
}

return (
<View>
<View style={{
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
}}>
  <Text>Filter by</Text>
  <Text>Sort by</Text>
</View>
<View style={{width: '100%',}}>
      {productData.map(item => {
          return <ProductCard data={item} key={item.productSKU} />
      })}
  </View>
</View>
```

and here is my product data

```
export const productData = [{
"productSKU": 1,
"productSize": "M",
"productColor": "pink",
"productImage": "'../assets/images/productimage/product1.jpg'",
"productDesc": "It's a nice blue dress.",
"productPrice": 150,
"productName": "LIANA"
```

it doesn't matter if I use "'../assets/images/productimage/product1.jpg'" or '../assets/images/productimage/product1.jpg' it still gives me an error

The error it give is unexpected token "," which it needs to change data.productImage to data,productImage which it obviously wrong

Comment: i want to add something, i try to change the data on my database from "productImage": "'../assets/images/productimage/product1.jpg'" to "productImage": require('../assets/images/productimage/product1.jpg') but it give me syntax error "none of these files exist: product1.jpg even though when I try to call it normally it will show up just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use require function to render image in this situation, normally in react-native expo app you have write down assets in app.json file to use it with require function.

Include your assest in app.json file like this:

```
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*",
      "assests/*"
    ],
```

Or without using assets you can use `{uri:"link"}` method in your situation.

`<Image source={{uri: "link"}} />`

Comment: thank you!!!! you're a lifesaver

change my code to <Image source={{uri: data.productImage,}} style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 250,
                        resizeMode: 'cover',
                    }} />

which I don't know why it works now and change the product image data to something like this "productImage": "https://static-id.zacdn.com/p/colorbox-1423-2035243-1.jpg" and it's work. thank you again ( *ﾉ_ _)ﾉﾉ ╮*_ _)╮